# How do I use a try/catch block for a MongoDB connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to check a connection to my MongoDB, should it be down I want to send myself an email. I can't seem to get my head around the try/catch element of what I want to do - I am fairly new to JavaScript.

Here is my code so far:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://myserver:port/";

function check() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, async (err, db) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(err)

        try {
            if(err == "MongoNetworkError") throw "No connection"
        }

        catch(err) {
            console.log("no connection")
        }

})
}
```

When a connection is established it prints `null`, when I trigger the error by turning off the server it doesn't print `"no connection"`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

When there is error during the connection, you will have `err != null`. That tells you there is a connection error and you can send the email there.

You do not need a custom try-catch block for that.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://myserver:port/";

function check() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, async (err, db) => {
            if (err) { //enter here whenever there is error
              console.log(err) // this gives you more information about the connection error
              if(err instanceof MongoClient.MongoNetworkError) {
                 console.log("no connection") // you can log "no connection" here
                //send email here
              }
            } 
            // go here if no error
    })         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm still a little confused. How do I get it to console log `"no connection"`  if the error is generated

Comment: @ESinclair I updated the answer for the "no connection" part and included some more explanation. Hope that helps

Comment: @ESinclair I missed the MongoNetworkError part in the previous answer. You can use `instanceof` to check what specific error it is and console `no connection` when needed.

Answer (score -1):

Since [`MongoClient.connect`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) returns a promise, you can use `async/await` to check for any errors as well as the client returned from the connection:

```
async function check() {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })

        if (!client) {
            // Send email
        }
    } catch(err) {
        if(err == "MongoNetworkError") {
            console.log("no connection")
        }

        console.log(err)
        // Send email
    }
}

check()
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. If there is a connection error the whole script fails and doesn't continue

Comment: If there is a connection error it will be caught in the `catch` block and you then decide what you want to do in that clause, why would you want to continue if there is no connection?

Comment: I have a function in the catch block (this sends an email), when the connection goes down it does not run this function?

Comment: basically if the connection goes down I need it to email the relevant people